# Google BigQuery API using Python client

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use the BigQuery Python API  ,
but upon the following command:

`client = bigquery.Client()`

I am getting an error that the file that stores the service account key can’t be found.

> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File
>   "C:\Projects\Agent Scoring-a5bf49c5af93.json" was not found.

I followed the instruction here 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries

The error message is not clear if the path to the file is known, how come it can’t be found.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Did you set up your development environment? Check out this link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup

Comment: Hi Claudio,
No I did not. I will check the Python 3 Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `bigquery.Client()` development [guidelines](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google-cloud-bigquery-client-client) the issue that you've discovered might be related to:

> **google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError** – Raised if credentials is not specified and the library fails to acquire default
>   credentials.

Therefore as @Claudio mentioned in the comment section, you have to apply the steps described in GCP Bigquery API library [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python), installing certain Bigquery Python [client](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) and propagating `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable that points to the JSON key file, more info about GCP authentication methods you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#authentication_strategies).